# SQL - Better way to create this nested Select case query

Tags: sql, performance, case

I have to retrieve the sum of amounts based on certain conditions. There are 2 tables

```
1. Stocks table
2. Payments table
```

This is the requirement

```
"Select all Stocks from Stocks table that has 
 RecordID is 9 
 If amount in Payment table is not null   
    ADD amount TO Stockamount
 else 
    find the greater number between Amt1 , Amt2, balAmt in Stocks table
    Multiply the number with 0.04  , 
    ADD this number to  Stockamount
 END-IF"
 Return Stockamount
```

NOTE: The amount values in all fields are stored as string. They need to be cast to int before multiplication. 
Also, the amount fields can be null, which gives an error when I typecast the field. I have tried to check for nulls in the case statement.

I have written the select case statement like so

```
select SUM("Amount") as "StockAmount" 
from (
    select 
        case 
            when ltrim(rtrim(b.c_amount)) <> '' 
                then cast(b.c_amount as int) 
            when ltrim(rtrim(a.c_balamt)) = '' and cast(a.c_amt1 as int)>=cast(a.c_amt2 as int) 
                then cast(a.c_amt1 as int)*0.04 
            when ltrim(rtrim(a.c_balamt)) = '' and cast(a.c_amt2 as int)>cast(a.c_amt1 as int) 
                then cast(a.c_amt2 as int)*0.04 
            when cast(a.c_amt1 as int)>=cast(a.c_balamt as int) and cast(a.c_amt1 as int)>=cast(a.c_amt2 as int) 
                then cast(a.c_amt1 as int)*0.04 
            when cast(a.c_amt2 as int)>=cast(a.c_balamt as int) and cast(a.c_amt2 as int)>cast(a.c_amt1 as int) 
                then cast(a.c_amt2 as int)*0.04 
            when cast(a.c_balamt as int)>=cast(a.c_amt1 as int) and cast(a.c_amt2 as int) <=cast(a.c_balamt as int) 
                then cast(a.c_balamt as int)*0.04 
            else 0 
        end as "Amount" 
    from STOCKS_TABLE a,
        PAYMENTS_TABLE b
    where a.c_recordid = 9 
        and substr(a.t_tradeline_id,3)=b.parent_id 
)
```

Is there a better way to write this query?

Comment: Why all those comparisons with empty strings? Are you storing numeric data in varchar? And having "NULL" as empty strings?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh yes the amount values are stored as string and they can be null. Since I need to multiply and add them up, i need to convert them from string to numeric. But before cast, i need to check for nulls, as cast on null values will fail